# Adding buttons in validation lines

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.1

I just started working with `laravel` and I was wondering if there is a way to put links/buttons in your validation lines.

For example I created a basic registration page (followed the `laravel` docs). When somebody is trying to register an account with a wrong email (only specific email account will be registered directly, the others will be put on a waiting list), the user will get a little error message saying that they will be put on a waiting list and a button if they would like to be on this waiting list.

Here is my code:

**Auth/AuthController**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'firstname' => 'required|max:255',
        'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
        'username' => 'required|max:50|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users|regex:/@student\.test\.be$/',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}
```

**Validation.php** //Custom Validation Language Lines

```
'email' => [
        'unique' => 'This email is already already registered',
        'required' => 'Email is required.',
        'regex' => 'some text <button>want to be on the waitinglist?</button>',
    ],
```

And then there is a basic register view with a form and the error messages

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            {{ $error }}
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be better of doing it in your view file, something like the following:

```php
@if (array_key_exists('regex', $errors->get('email')))
    some text <button>want to be on the waitinglist?</button>
@endif
```

**EDIT:**

You can also change `{{ $error }}` to `{!! $error !!}` to display HTML properly.

```html
@if (count($errors) > 0)
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        {!! $error !!}
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif
```